# Supported Azure Hosting Options for ServiceControl and ServicePulse

Tags: azure, nservicebus, azure-service-fabric

We are looking at hosting endpoints in Azure Service Fabric clusters using Azure based transports.  We'd like to host ServiceControl and ServicePulse in Azure as well.  It seems as though ServicePulse can be hosted as an AppService, but what do we do with ServiceControl?

What are the supported ways to host ServiceControl in Azure without maintaining a VM?  Are there plans to enable ServiceFabric deployments?

Comment: Added an Issue to GitHub: https://github.com/Particular/ServiceControl/issues/972

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend investigating whether you can run it as a Container. That could save you some troubles with installing, versioning and prerequisites.

Comment: We were hoping to avoid learning containers, but that is very feasible.  We could host the container in Service Fabric.

Comment: Learning about containers is inevitable :-)